# routing in html5 backbone-marionette app with pushState: true is failing if more than one component to url

Tags: html, marionette, pushstate

I have an backbone-marionette app routing issue driving me nuts.  I setup Marionette.AppRouter to for each module I have.  The routing works fine as long as there is only one component to the url.  The moment we had a second "directory" or even an :id, I get syntax errors in the browser for every file included in the index.html.. including the index.html itself.

for example
myapp/articles works fine.  myapp/articles/78 gives me the issues.  I even tested just creating two appRoutes in the router... "article" and "article/something".  I can go to `http://myapp` or `http://myapp/article` but `http://myapp.article/something` gives the syntax and never processes anything.

### My article_app.js below shows trying to get article/:id to work.. but that fails everytime with the error posted below all this

```
azBest.module("ArticleApp",function(ArticleApp, azBest, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

ArticleApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        "article": "returnToResultsPage",
        "article/:id": "test"
    },
});

var API = {

    test: function(id) {
        console.log("testing...id:" + id);
        azBest.trigger("storefront:show");
    },
    returnToResultsPage: function() {
        azBest.trigger("storefront:show");
    }
};

azBest.on("article:show", function(model) {
    Backbone.history.navigate("article/"+model.get("articleid"));
    azBest.ArticleApp.Show.Controller.showArticle(model);
});

azBest.addInitializer(function(){
    new ArticleApp.Router({
        controller: API
    });
});
```

});

---

Captured from firefox's console.

SyntaxError: syntax error

78 (line 276)
SyntaxError: syntax error

json2.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

unders....min.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

backbo....min.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

marion....min.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

spin.min.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

spin.jquery.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

jquery...-min.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

app.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

storefront_app.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

results_app.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

article_app.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

views.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

featuredItems.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

popularItems.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

ads.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

articles.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

list_view.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

list_c...ller.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_view.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_c...ller.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_view.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_c...ller.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_view.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_c...ller.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_view.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_c...ller.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

list_view.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

list_c...ller.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_view.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: syntax error

show_c...ller.js (line 1)
ReferenceError: azBest is not defined

azBest.start();

78 (line 276)

---

I am at a loss as to what is causing the syntax errors.  Each error except the first and last seems to be pointing at `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue...

When the apache rewrite does its thing, it changes the base so none of my included scripts are found correctly.

To fix this, I changed my htdocs to:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L,QSA]
```

I also changed the included scripts to be relative and added  to the head of the index.html.